# How can i convert a sed command to its PowerShell equivalent?

Tags: windows, powershell, sed, replace

**Editor's note**:

- The macOS `sed` command below performs an *in-place* (`-i ''`) string-substitution (string-replacement) operation on the given file, i.e. it transforms the file's existing content. The specific substitution shown, `s/././g`, replaces all non-newline characters (regex metacharacter `.`) with *verbatim* `.` characters, so *be careful when trying the command yourself*.
- While the *intended* question may ultimately be a different one, as written the question *is* well-defined, and can be answered to show the *full* PowerShell equivalent of the `sed` command (a partial translation is in the question itself), notably including the *in-place updating of the file*.

---

I have a mac command and i need it to run on windows. I have no experience in mac whatsoever.

```
sed -i '' 's/././g' dist/index.html
```

After research i found that i should use

```
get-content path | %{$_ -replace 'expression','replace'}
```

but can't get it to work yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**:

- **The assumption is that `s/././g` in your `sed` command is just a *example* string substitution** that you've chosen as a placeholder for real-world ones. What this example substitution does is to replace all characters other than newnlines (regex `.`) with a *verbatim* `.` **Therefore, do *not* run the commands below as-is on your files, unless you're prepared to have their characters turn into `.`**

The **direct translation of your `sed` command, which performs *in-place updating of the input file***, is ([`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) is the name of the cmdlet that the built-in `%` alias refers to):

```sh
(Get-Content dist/index.html) | 
  ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '.', '.' } |
    Set-Content dist/index.html -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Or, more efficiently:

```sh
(Get-Content -ReadCount 0 dist/index.html) -replace '.', '.' | Set-Content dist/index.html -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-ReadCount 0` reads the lines into a *single array* before outputting the result, instead of the default behavior of emitting each line *one by one* to the pipeline.</sup>

Or, even more efficiently, if *line-by-line* processing isn't required and the `-replace` operation can be applied *to the entire file content*, using the `-Raw` switch:

```sh
(Get-Content -Raw dist/index.html) -replace '.', '.' | Set-Content -NoNewLine dist/index.html -WhatIf
```

Note:

- `-replace`, the [regular-expression-based string replacement operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) uses the syntax `<input> -replace <regex>, <replacement>` and *invariably* performs global replacements (as requested by the `g` option in your `sed` command), i.e. replaces *all* matches it finds.

  - Unlike `sed`'s regular expressions, however, PowerShell's are case-*insensitive* by default; to make them case-*sensitive*, use the `-creplace` operator variant.
- Note the required `(...)` around the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) call, which ensures that the file is read into memory in full and closed again *first*, which is the prerequisite for being able to rewrite the file with [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) in the same pipeline.

  - *Caveat*: While unlikely, this approach can result in data loss, namely if the write operation that saves back to the input file gets interrupted.
- You may need `-Encoding` with `Set-Content` to ensure that the rewritten file uses the same character encoding as the original content - `Get-Content` reads text files into .NET strings recognizing a variety of encodings, and no information is retained as to what encoding was encountered.
- Except with the `Get-Content -Raw` / `Set-Content -NoNewLine` solution, which preserves the original newline format, the output file will use the *platform-native* newline format - CRLF (`\r\n`) on Windows, LF (`\n`) on Unix-like platforms - irrespective of which format the input file originally used.

Comment: Would using `Get-Content -Raw` change anything; better or worse. Are there any hazards in processing markup language as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/447901?

Comment: @lit, if _line-by-line_ processing isn't required, `-Raw`, which reads the entire file into a _single, multiline string_, provides a significant performance boost. As the post you link to argues, regexes shouldn't be used to parse markup languages. Please also see my update re `-ReadCount 0`.